# Вывести значение, которое будет получено позже

Tags: php, массивы

**Пример кода:**

```
$list = array(
    array('name' => 'test'),
    array('name' => ''),
    array('name' => 'test2')
);
echo 'В этом списке N элементов:<br>';
$i = 0;
foreach ($list as $el){
    if(empty($el['name'])) continue;
    echo ++$i.') '.$el['name'].'<br>';
}
echo 'Вот это значение нужно вывести в место "N" до списка: '.$i;
```

**Результат:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как правильно вывести это значение, до того как ещё подсчитанно оно?
Только подготавливать заранее массив, отсортировав его и выводить длину массива (придётся два раза перебирать массив) или есть более правильные решения?

Comment: можно попробовать внутри цикла не выводить значения, а собирать из них строку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такое имеет место быть, но лучше все таки используйте патерн MVC или MVVC. И данные готовьте не во время вывода, а перед их выводом!